# Export SQL Server query results to CSV and handle embedded newlines, quotes, commas etc

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I am using [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to export data from an SQL query to a CSV file and I'm having issues with fields that contain embedded newlines, commas, quotes etc.

I have a table with two columns `Id` and `Name`.

My `bcp` command looks like this:

```
bcp "select Id, Name from MyTable" queryout ./results.csv -c -t, -U SA -S localhost
```

And the resulting CSV file looks like this:

```
1,Quick brown fox
2,The quick brown fox
jumps over the
lazy dog
3,This is a "quoted" value
4,Quick, Brown, Fox
```

Is there a way to have `bcp` automatically quote fields, escape any existing quotes etc so that the generated CSV file is actually valid?

Ideally I'd like the csv file to look something like this:

```
"1","Quick brown fox"
"2","The quick brown fox
jumps over the
lazy dog"
"3","This is a \"quoted\" value"
"4","Quick, Brown, Fox"
```

Answer (score 0):

normally I use -replace in powershell to format the output of BCP, like following,

```
    [string]$rowStart=[System.Guid][System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    [string]$fieldTerm=[System.Guid][System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    [string]$rowTerm=[System.Guid][System.Guid]::NewGuid()

    bcp "select format(Id, '$rowStart#'), Name from Test.dbo.MyTable" queryout "C:\temp\yourfile.txt" -c -T -t"$fieldTerm" -r"$rowTerm" -S"localhost"

    $rowEndTerm='"' + $rowTerm

    cat "C:\temp\yourfile.txt" `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"', '\"'  } `
    | ForEach-Object { $_  -replace $rowStart, '"'} `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $fieldTerm, '","'} `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$rowTerm", $rowEndTerm} `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $rowTerm, "`r`n"} `
    > "C:\temp\results.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

couple of parts to the answers.

1. to get your fields quoted, you'll need to use a format file to specify custom field terminators. There are many answers already on SO that cover this.
2. For the crlfs in your data... it looks like BCP did what you wanted it to do. it printed them out because they are in the data. it sounds like what you want is to clean those out of the data even though they are included in your source table. Just handle this with the "replace" function in your query. get rid of your "select *" and replace with a full selection of the columns you want and use "replace" on column "name".